# Hive error while querying external table containing flume stream

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive, flume

On CDH 5.4, I'm trying to create a demo on Twitter analytics using:

1. Flume for capturing the tweets into a HDFS folder
2. Hive for querying the tweets using Hive-Serde

The step 1 is successful. I can see that the tweets are being captured and directed properly to the desired HDFS folder. I observe that a temporary file is created first, which then is converted to permanent file:

```
-rw-r--r--   3 root hadoop       7548 2015-10-06 06:39 /user/flume/tweets/FlumeData.1444127932782
-rw-r--r--   3 root hadoop      10034 2015-10-06 06:39 /user/flume/tweets/FlumeData.1444127932783.tmp
```

I'm using the below table declaration:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets(
    id bigint, 
    created_at string, 
    lang string, 
    source string, 
    favorited boolean, 
    retweet_count int, 
    retweeted_status 
    struct<text:string,user:struct<screen_name:string,name:string>>,
    entities struct<urls:array<struct<expanded_url:string>>,
    user_mentions:array<struct<screen_name:string,name:string>>,
    hashtags:array<struct<text:string>>>,
    text string,
    user struct<location:string,geo_enabled:string,screen_name:string,name:string,friends_count:int,followers_count:int,statuses_count:int,verified:boolean,utc_offset:int,time_zone:string>,
    in_reply_to_screen_name string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://master.ds.com:8020/user/flume/tweets';
```

But when I query this table, I get the below error:

```
hive> select count(*) from tweets;

Ended Job = job_1443526273848_0140 with errors
...
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreation
        ... 11 more

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/flume/tweets/FlumeData.1444128601078.tmp
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:66)
        ...

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:

Stage-Stage-1: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 1.19 sec   HDFS Read: 10492 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
```

I think the problem pertains to the temporary file, which the map-reduce job spawned by the Hive query, not being read. Can there be some work-around or config change to handle this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience and I resolved it by adding to my flume config files the hdfs sink configurations below 

`some_agent.hdfssink.hdfs.inUsePrefix = .
hdfs.inUseSuffix = .temp`

Hope it helps you.